# Missing XML in Twitter API

Tags: xml, json, twitter, hashtag

I'm having some little issues pulling data from Twitter. Basically I am  building a desktop Java application that will search for certain hashtags. 
To do so I must pull XML or JSON files from Twitter , as i understood ,for every post in twitter it is possible to pull it via XML or JSON , correct me if I'm wrong?

It is easier for me to do it via XML ,because I have ,at least , some experience with it. But Twitter API is fully translated to JSON , so i will ask you all for two things:

1. Is there some good resources on web that has good data on XML in Twitter (like twitter api used to be)
2. Can some1 help me find XML and JSON examples of tweets that are sent over web , I'm having tough time finding them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using Twitter in a Java app, there is no need to work with JSON or XML directly, you can use [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html).